# How to define the Nabla-Operator

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definition

As I began to teach myself in differential geometry, I finally used to use the Nabla-Operator.

I know and understand its usage as in

$$
\nabla f := \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{∂f}{∂x_1} & \frac{∂f}{∂x_2} & \cdots & \frac{∂f}{∂x_n} \end{matrix} \right)^\intercal
$$

but in many books I read a pure definition of $\nabla$:
$$ \nabla := \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{∂}{∂x_1} & \frac{∂}{∂x_2} & \cdots & \frac{∂}{∂x_n} \end{matrix} \right) ^ \intercal $$

which seems to be just a visualisation of the content, because it's mathematically false $-$ an equation needs to have two *evaluatable terms* on both sides, but an operator is not a value.

For example, the derivation operator can conformly be defined as
$$ \frac{∂}{∂x_i}: ℝ → ℝ, \quad f ↦ \frac{∂f}{∂x_i} := \lim_{x_i→0}{\frac{f(x_1,\cdots,x_i+h,\cdots,x_n)-f(_1,\cdots,x_i,\cdots,x_n)}{h}} $$

But the Nabla-Operator is applied in multiple ways; therefore, one cannot define it as a function.

Do I suppose rightly that there does not exists an explicit definition, or does there exist some kind of ‘trick’?

Comment: What kind of function is the function $f$ that you want to apply the nabla operator to?

Comment: I don't really want to apply the nabla operator to anything, I just want to define it explicitly (if possible)… but in most cases, $ f: ℝ^3 → ℝ^3 $.

Comment: The differentiation operator maps the some space of functions into some other space of functions. It does not make any sense to write: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry for that, it was just a try to define the partial derivative operator. But the basic question is: How can one define an operator?

Comment: I don't agree that the "pure" definition is "mathematically false" - the distinction between an operator and a value is a completely artificial one. At best it's possibly a slight abuse of notation; but if you define the action of a vector of operators to be the componentwise action then it's fine. Anyway, what's wrong with taking the definition you gave for the partial derivative and inserting it $n$ times into the first definition you gave for $\nabla$?

Comment: Your last idea sounds great, but how would it look like?

Comment: @SergioParreiras How would a ‘space of functions’ be written? Sorry for the question, these are just the small things I have (and want) to improve.

Comment: We can define $D: C^k(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C^{k-1}(\mathbb{R})$ by $D(f)=f^\prime$ where $C^k$ is the set of functions that have a continuous k-th derivative.

Comment: Why can't you define $\nabla: C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \left( C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)\right)^n$ by $\nabla \left(f\right)=(\frac{\partial}{\partial_1}f,\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial_n}f)$ ?

Comment: @SergioParreiras: do you really think that your definition is even well-defined?

Comment: [This might be helpful.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029596/52893)

Comment: @Laters there is a typo should be $C^{k-1}$ in the  image but I really think with this correction the definition is OK. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is *Operator Calculus* or alternatively *Operational Calculus*. Here is an introductory [(PDF) document](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2004/uitboek.pdf) . Other references are easily found on the internet, such as [Fractional Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) (Wikipedia), [What is operator calculus?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/what-is-operator-calculus) (MSE), [How to make sense of this calculus notation, Advanced College Level](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552395/how-to-make-sense-of-this-calculus-notation-advanced-college-level/552832#552832) (MSE).

Answer (score 1):

I find this an interesting question, because it appeared to me also when I studied multivariable calculus. First of all, "an equation needs to have two evaluatable terms on both sides, but an operator is not a value" is meaningless (and also false, no matter what meaning you give to "evaluatable terms"). What does this even mean? Also $\nabla:=(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n)^T$ is not a mere equation, it is a *definition*. Your only objection can be to the meaning of the right hand sie.

"But the Nabla-Operator is applied in multiple ways; therefore, one cannot define it as a function. Do I suppose rightly that there does not exists an explicit definition, or does there exist some kind of ‘trick’?" Doesn't make any sense either, in particular "therefore, one cannot define it as a function" is a non sequitur. Counterexample: let $\Omega\subset\mathbf{R}^n$ be open, and $X$ be the set of all functions $\Omega\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ such that $\partial_i f$ exists for all $i$. Also let $Y$ be the set of all maps $\Omega\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^n$. Then we define $\nabla:X\rightarrow Y$ by $\nabla f:=(\partial_1 f,\ldots,\partial_n f)^T$. It is a perfectly ok definition. You see, in the definition it is UNDERSTOOD (IMPLICIT) how the function $\nabla$ is to be defined (one does not need "operator calculus" or whatever), writing $\nabla:=(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n)^T$ already suggests this definition. The symbol $(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n)^T$ should not be understood as an element of $\mathbf{R}^n$ (because it isn't one), but in the sense I made precise.